# Transmutation from thin air. Literally(ish)

Tags: science-based, nuclear

There are many stories of converting one element into another (such as the story of the Philosopher's Stone), but to actually mutate one material into another (at least with our our current understand of the atom) we need a source of electrons, protons, and neutrons.  And what more convenient source than to take from the air around us?

This process is perfect, but naive, so you don't need to worry about Gamma Radiation or Leptons from removing the protons and neutrons, but the system is inherently stupid(only smart enough to be given steps).

> **My Question:** Given that my machine draws from everyday air to create any substance, what are the steps that would take the most optimal number of protons, electrons, and neutrons from the air's elements.

**Conditions**

- The machine can only remove a single elementary particle (electron, proton, neutron) per-step.  It must draw what it needs from ordinary air.
- If you have a bond such as a molecule or a diatomic molecule, the machine can separate it into its base elements, and it does so automatically(for the scope of this question). This is mostly to simplify the process, so you don't worry about water vapor in the air, you can just deal with the Hydrogen(which basically has removed as many as possible already), and Oxygen.
- The machine cannot hold those elementary particles in reserve for later steps.  In other words, there's no adding them back into the elements. Whatever the machine cannot use from the air element or molecule it took from the air must be able to be released safely back into the air.
- The results of the process cannot include unsafe levels of radiation or unstable molecules or isotopes.
- The process cannot be harmful to the machine's operator, while not in the room, he is not shielded by anything, but the walls(which are negligible, not made of lead or something) and any lingering effects that would prevent the operator from filling the room up with more air, entering, and then restarting the process.
- The process of harvesting and reconfiguring the elementary particles should remain undetectable (another reason why radiation should be kept to a minimum).

**Extra Credit**

- Please let me know what stopped you from deconstructing a particular molecule further than you did (e.g., "removing one more electron would cause nuclear fission" or "would leave remaining molecule in a highly unstable state").

Comment: Of potential interest would be the book [Bloom](http://www.epiphyte.net/SF/bloom.html) by Wil McCarthy.  In that book, they had Ladder-Down reactors, which could create any low atomic weight atom from larger atoms, like Uranium.

Comment: *"The radiation isn't being shielded":* what radiation? You did not say nothing about no radiation! Anyway, to the question "how do you remove the most neutrons, protons, and electrons from air, without the radiation being harmful or suspicious and detectable?" the answer is obviously, in a bottle or othe suitable recipient. You pump the air in the bottle (no radiation!) and take the bottle with you, thus removing *all* the neutrons, protons, and electrons *together*...

Comment: @AlexP Perhaps I stated the question in a confusing way, but the way I meant it was: What is a safe way to remove individual protons, neutrons, or electrons over and over from air to make them literally different elements. I said that it wasn't being shielded to point out that even radiation that could be prevented by say a lead wall would still be detectable. Some isotopes can be radioactive or easily detected, even at low atomic numbers to my knowledge. The nature of removing them one by one could create an element like C-14. Please, if that idea is flawed, post an answer explaining that.

Comment: @CortAmmon I'll have to read that sometime, that sounds sort of like the idea chain that made me post this question

Comment: Do you want hadnwavium answers?

Comment: Can the machine split diatomic molecules?

Comment: It's rather  ̶n̶u̶c̶l̶e̶a̶r̶ unclear what you are trying to do. You want to use air as reservoir of subatomic particles for construction of heavier elements particle by particle? If so, yo are aware that 12 grams of carbon contain ~6*10^23 atoms? If each modification took nanosecond, that's still billiard times too slow to be useful.

Comment: Yes its not clear what would constitute a good answer, or even an answer that you would be interested in. Can you reword it to specify what problems need to be over come?

Comment: I edited this question in an attempt to save it from a close vote, but I would like to remind the OP that it is impossible to derive the answers he/she wants without knowing the target of the mutation (I arbitrarily made it gold).  The equation will change for every target (whether it be a "simple" element like gold or a supercomputer).  Consequently, this question may still be too broad.

Comment: @JBH Is it not clear that the target is air? If you asking about how it stores it, that's outside of my personal question. Just assume it's a perfect storing system. If it's absolutely vital I can edit it, but it gets into the intrinsics of my story.

Comment: I would suggest allowing some kind of battery storage.  The universal building block of everything is energy e=mc^2.  If you can convert the atoms in the air to energy you should be able to make any atom from that energy.  Actually implementing this is Star Trek replicator technology.

Comment: @cybernard yeah, I get that, but when the stone was made(albeit it still with futuristic technology outside of the scope) they didn't understand that. I may consider making that an improvement to it later.

Comment: @Bellerophon I've edited it, along with fixing a edit that changed the intent of the question(unfortunately this is likely because I stated the question badly, and I think they were only trying to help), to answer your question, I didn't actually think of diatomic molecules, but unless there's something about separating molecules I don't understand, I think it should be able to do it easily. The reasons for it is *completely* out of scope for this question(I've been building this universe in my head for a while), but it should be able to.

Comment: @DavidArchibald, your **source** is air.  Your **target** is the material you're trying to build, unless I've missed something?  The "program" will change for whatever it is you're trying to build, so one equation is going to give you a taste of things, but nothing more.

Comment: David, while I understand why you changed your question after my edit, you appear to be missing the point of why I changed it the way I did.  No one can answer the question as currently stated.  The "steps" to gain the most "optimal" elementary particles is different for each item you want to create (I suggested gold to keep it simple).  As stated the question is too broad and should be closed.

Comment: @jbh The question isn't converting air into another element. It is breaking up and storing the protons neutrons and electrons of air so they could be used to create stuff later.

Comment: @Bellerophon Thank you for your comment that really clears it up, I was thinking of how to state that in the best way.

Comment: This question has been edited so many times, that it has lost its significance. It is no longer possible to ascertain the essence of the original OP. Earlier answers no longer apply. Therefore, can ANY answer address this progression of edits? Each one materially changes the question.

Comment: @JustinThyme The unfortunate thing is that I've only changed it back to the original question's intent, but I wasn't able to fix it fast enough in some cases, so the entire intent has been changed multiple times, perhaps I should've left it. I am not a veteran, and this question really has been turned into a bit of a mess. I'm sure it was only people's intent to *clear up* the confusion, and explain why some of the conflicts in the edits wouldn't be physically possible, but now I have answers that don't... answer it. I'm not sure how to continue on now.

Comment: Essentially, the question has been reduced to 'How do you make a silk purse out of a sow's ear? Describe the steps necessary. Oh, and you can not kill the sow in the process.

Comment: @JustinThyme I've set up a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66891/transmutation-from-thin-air-literallyish) so that we don't have a billion comments.

Comment: At this point, I an thinking that you will just have to assume you have a device that does what you want, and leave the details of how it does it, out. The process would have to work so fast, decomposing and reconstructing, to provide a sufficient quantity in a reasonable time, that I don't think the radiation would be much higher than, or much different from, background radiation. Any interim step would last only microseconds. We just don't know how to do this yet, but that doesn't make it impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Electrons can be harvested reasonably safely, we do it with electric generators all the time. The problem you will face is that atoms, all atoms, tend to dump large quantities of [Gamma Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray) when they rearrange themselves internally, and they will rearrange themselves every time you pluck out a proton or neutron. That's going to need a *lot* of shielding, like centimetres of Lead heavy shielding. Even with sufficient shielding to take care of the Gamma internal changes can also result in the production of strange, and detectable, particles called [Leptons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton), usually in the form of Muons and Neutrinos, which you really *can't* shield for because they can pass through several miles of normal matter without flinching.

Comment: Genertors cause electrons to move, but they don't deplete anything.  A battery is the closest we come to harvesting electrons.

Comment: I was aware of the difficulty of removing particles from the nucleus, and the philosopher's stone should take care of it by itself, (a better system to remove them outside of the scope), but not the radiation that would come from after from the resulting isotopes, because it is an inherently dumb system that is only capable of removing a proton neutron or electron over and over.

Comment: @JBH and capacitors. They store electrons in massive quantities.

Comment: @JBH Generators still remove electrons from one place and move them elsewhere, (if they didn't you wouldn't get any flow of electricity) that is the definition of a harvest, taking material elsewhere.

Comment: No, to harvest means to deplete something.  There is less of what you started with at the source than after the harvest is over.  Generators only facilitate movement, but unless a battery or capacitor (good point, @JustinThyme) is involved, an electrical circuit must be a closed loop.  Generators don't harvest.  Heck, Ash, change the word "generator" in your answer to "battery" and move on.

Comment: Semantics. Actually, a complete circuit is not required for electron flow, just for CONTINUOUS electron flow. Static electricity is the movement of electrons from one point to another. Lightning, for example.

Comment: @JBH Harvests remove something from a given location yes? Generators do in fact remove electrons from a given location, they are replaced from the environment around them, that's why you get "ground return currents" where electrons flow back towards generation sites from major consumers like cities. This is also why [Van de Graaf Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator) create sparks they create a local imbalance of electrons. A battery is only a conversion/storage device it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: The trick is to keep production low enough so that it is masked by background radiation. One at a time.

Comment: @JustinThyme Yeah if you put the Philosopher's Stone somewhere with a reasonably high background count you could get away with a lot, hell depending on rate of consumption you might even get away with it just because you're on a granite floor.

Comment: I apologize, it violates my engineering sensibilities to see it that way.  It's like saying that a paddlewheel or a pump that serves the purpose of moving the water along a closed loop (like an amusement ride) is "harvesting" the water.  It isn't.  Only when the loop is broken can harvesting occur.  Hence, battery.

Comment: @JBH Okay I can see that to a point but by the same token a battery is a generator too, just chemical rather than mechanical. Are you thinking as in charging a battery and taking it away as a harvest?

Answer (score 1):

### All of them if you don't care about the material you create with.

This answer supposes you can effectively remove protons, electrons and neutrons without the act of removing them creating radiations.

The comment about pumping the air in a bottle was pretty clever, and it is still valid even if you ask for the elements to be pumped one by one (it only becomes very very tedious, and potentially too long, but if you can do it infinitely fast it works).

The idea is that you start by isolating one molecule from the air (DiAzote and DiOxygen mostly) then you take one electron from it (it makes an ion, which is not radioactive), then one proton (it makes something neutral, maybe a bit radioactive but it is still only one molecule so the radioactivity is very small), then start again, removing a few protons when it makes the molecule more stable. In the end you will have removed all the molecule, so the result is stable. Start again with the next molecule.

This suppose that you are reforming molecules somewhere, using everything you take from the air. You have a big margin for that, but if you want to create a specific material with that (like gold) you will probably have to waste a big of the elements to keep the proportion between protons and neutrons. If the material doesn't matter then you can create solid air or whatever that would use up to all the air (just keep enough of it to breathe)

Answer (score 1):

## Elementary particles are **not** storable

From a comment that you posted:

> What is a safe way to remove individual protons, neutrons, or electrons over and over from air to make them literally different elements.

The answer is: nothing, **because they are not elements**

The elementary particles are not elements. If the elementary particles had been such that the atoms could be taken apart and the particles stored like elements, then the Philosopher's Stone would not have been the magical thing that it is, it would just have been a part of junior high-school physics.

An atom is not anything like a loose pile of things that you can just pick apart and put together willy-nilly. The [fundamental forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction) of reality very effectively prevent that. And while electrons and protons are easy to obtain,  (ionize hydrogen for protons, use a plain old cathode ray for electrons), there is no way you can store them like LEGO® pieces in a box. And neutrons definitely cannot be obtained easy nor stored free.

The bullet points you have written are mutually exclusive: if you break apart an atom — or put one together again — **you will get radiation**. There is no way around that unless you employ magic.

Also, as it turns out, **the elementary particles do not get along well with their own kind**. Hence splitting things into its elementary particles and storing those together is an absolutely **terrible** idea. [xkcd: what-if explains why](https://what-if.xkcd.com/140/).

TL;DR? You create a black hole. Bye bye Earth...

Comment: While I was gone, the question was edited to make it more clear, but it changed the intent. That sentence, along with others I added was an attempt to clear it up; that we were talking about air, and extracting particles from it, but in the end it has appeared to make it more confusing. I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66891/transmutation-from-thin-air-literallyish) to see what we can do to fix the confusion.

Comment: Theoretically you can use a magnetic bottle for the Protons and Electrons can't you? In very low numbers as I recall, like two or three in a cubic centimetre.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the answer generated in chat official, the use of a [fusor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor) might provide a useful lead.

> A fusor is a device that uses an electric field to heat ions to
>   conditions suitable for nuclear fusion. The machine generates an
>   electric potential difference between two metal cages inside a vacuum.
>   Positive ions fall down this voltage drop, building up speed. If they
>   collide in the center, they can fuse. This is a type of inertial
>   electrostatic confinement device.

Much credit to @MichaelK for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please edit your first sentence to complete the thought(s). (Arguably, you should form 2 sentences from it). Au exists as <sup>196</sup>Au with atomic number 79. That means it has 118 neutrons, and 79 electrons and protons. BY DEFINITION, chemical reactions do not change sub-atomic particles, nor do they change the nucleus of any atom. So, the "reactions" aren't chemical, they're nuclear, and so are the "equations".
 Many sources, including Wikipedia contain charts indicating which isotopes are stable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope#/media/File:Isotopes_and_half-life.svg.
You should look at that, and pay special attention to the rows (Neutron number is on the vertical axis). The dark brown, almost black cells are stable. So, what you wish to do is by taking either a step up or a step right to move from one of the atoms (specific isotopes, actually) in air H,C,O,N,Ar,etc. to move to (79,118). I'm not going to do that drudge work for you. You'll note that there are several rows between At. No. 19 and 79 that *do not have* a dark brown cell in them. That is, you can't get there from here without going through a radioactive element, even if you assume you can magically manipulate the atoms so that the one you 'tear a piece off of' remains, and the new isotope/element also doesn't spontaneously decay. However, it might be possible (again, I'm unwilling to do your work for you) to chose a path through an isotope which has very little high-energy radioactivity/radiation decay modes (Wikipedia has charts on the types of decay, and their energy, I believe. If not Wikipedia, then one of the (US) National Labs will have it.) So, in the cases where you have to "cross" a radioactive element (like Potassium, K) you should choose the route which has decay products which are most easily contained. The obvious question is why should that be a problem for a technology that can manipulate individual nucleons? It seems inconsistent to me that you can manipulate atoms and yet not be able to contain the radiation.

Comment: Please add some blank lines to your answer to make it more readable.

Comment: If the process is fast enough, what is the problem with unstable elements? Unless they have a half-life less than microseconds, the process should quickly pass them before they decay. The problem would be the containment vessel to hold one atom at a time as it is being built up. The radiation given off by just one atom would probably not be distinguishable from background radiation.

Comment: You're totally right, if it weren't for the fact that it's not containing the radiation/gamma rays/leptons/neutrinos of removing protons and neutrons; it's not making any(whether this is possible or not is out of scope). Apparently someone(this is likely my fault) misunderstood my question and edited it for me. I don't really care about the second half, actually using it such as their edit of gold. I want to know how many electrons, protons, and neutrons, can be removed from air etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops! <sup>197</sup>Au. Typo.
Also note that a pound of gold is about 1.5E24 atoms. Between <sup>40</sup>Ar and <sup>197</sup>Au there would be 39+106= 145 steps. To convert a pound of gold in a minute would be 1.5E24x145 ~ 220E24 ~ 2E26 steps which works out to 2E26/60 = 3E24 steps per second meaning each step would take far less time than even the fastest chemical reaction. Meaning the chemistry is irrelevant here, don't worry that converting Oxygen to Fluorine might *chemically* react. It won't have anywhere near enough time to do any chemistry.

Comment: You should edit your original post rather than creating a new one with the correction.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! As @JBH said, it's best practise to [edit your original answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/94404/edit) in order to keep it right and avoid clutter and confusion, then delete this answer. Thanks!